# free-jqGrid Filter toolbar shunt subgrid column width plus

Tags: filter, toolbar, free-jqgrid, subgrid

I'm using free-jqGrid 4.13.3.
I composed a grid with filter toolbar and this grid has subgrids elements such in this screenshot :
[image]
The subgrid column (which contains plus and minus signs) appears in filter toolbar, this has been ripped on left and make last column without filter, as it is on his left, under the dog icon.

So search in "N°" column doesn't match because ripped on left.

Same thing with this other screenshot :
[image]

I hope I am well understood with my explanation.

Please is there somebody who can drive me to correct my mistake ?
Many thanks in advance

Cheers

Jihel

Comment: Could you provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem? I tried to reproduces the problem, but I couldn't. Please use non-minimized JS file (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) of the latest free jqGrid 4.13.4 in the demo.

Answer (score 0):

and many thanks for your answer

I read again my code and have found I let in place one line where I hide the "th.jqgh_subgrid" column in main grid, when before I would want subgrid columns with plus/minus sign doesn't appear.

Sorry for the inconvenience as now the filter toolbar runs fine.

Have a nice day

Cheers

Jihel